# What is the most efficient way to monitor the number of context switches in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, profiling, arm, embedded-linux

I would like to have a total statistics of the following:

1. How many `softirq` occurred ?
2. How many `interrupts` occurred ?
3. How many `context switches` occurred ?

I know you can use [`pidstat`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-monitor-process-using-pidstat/), `cat /proc/interrupts` and `/cat/proc/softirqs`. But using them is too much overhead.

- **How can I get the bottom line values for `{1-3}` without working with `/proc` and in the fastest way?**
- **can I use [ftrace](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt) to help me tracking about the events?**

I am going to use a high resolution timers for monitoring the system:

- [LWN article](http://lwn.net/Articles/167897/)
- [IBM developer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-timers-list/index.html)
- [hrtimer](https://export.writer.zoho.com/public/rreginelli/Chapter-5---High-Resolution-Timers-Final1/fullpage)

Comment: We might be able to help you more if you explained what you are trying to do at a higher level...

Comment: I would like to set a periodical function will be scheduled with timer, where the delta between two sequential execution is a function(mathematical) of the machine IPS, number of interrupts & softirq & context switches occurred thanks @thkala

Comment: What kind of interval accuracy are you hoping for? Because even high-precision timers are not quite as precise as one might expect when it comes to scheduling operations...

Comment: I want the accuracy to be at least the time it takes the cpu to perform 10k assembly instructions (on ARM) @thkala

Comment: look into hw performance monitors and linux's perf

Comment: @auselen can you please supply links, I want to do it in kernel space and to be the least intrusive I can be

Comment: @0x90: How long would that be in real time units for your hardware? Some ARM processors (e.g. ARM-Cortex A9) can do two instructions per cycle, which boils down to 5us for a 1GHz processor. I doubt you can get a scheduling timer with that accuracy, unless you are willing to use some sort of busy-wait loop.

Comment: @thkala after careful calculation I need it to be accurate in 320 us, what do you think now?

Comment: @0x90: Considering that the system timer on Linux can get down to 1ms at most and that the scheduling latency for userspace threads is probably even more unpredictable, I'd say that you cannot achieve that kind of accuracy easily, if at all.

Comment: @thkala what do you think about this http://lwn.net/Articles/167897/ 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-timers-list/index.html https://export.writer.zoho.com/public/rreginelli/Chapter-5---High-Resolution-Timers-Final1/fullpage ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check Linux's [perf subsystem](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) it is the way you need to gain performance counters soft or hard from a Linux system.

Answer (score 6):

Use [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial), for example:

```
# perf stat -B dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000

1000000+0 records in
1000000+0 records out
512000000 bytes (512 MB) copied, 0.956217 s, 535 MB/s

 Performance counter stats for 'dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000':

            5,099 cache-misses             #      0.005 M/sec (scaled from 66.58%)
          235,384 cache-references         #      0.246 M/sec (scaled from 66.56%)
        9,281,660 branch-misses            #      3.858 %     (scaled from 33.50%)
      240,609,766 branches                 #    251.559 M/sec (scaled from 33.66%)
    1,403,561,257 instructions             #      0.679 IPC   (scaled from 50.23%)
    2,066,201,729 cycles                   #   2160.227 M/sec (scaled from 66.67%)
              217 page-faults              #      0.000 M/sec
                3 CPU-migrations           #      0.000 M/sec
               83 context-switches         #      0.000 M/sec
       956.474238 task-clock-msecs         #      0.999 CPUs

       0.957617512  seconds time elapsed
```

Comment: I want to do it in the kernel source code. but thanks it is helpful too :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get all of this information out of `/proc` with some level of resolution, and if you need more rez you can tweak the kernel of your embedded system.

The information you want can be monitored with `$ vmstat 1` and you can check the source to vmstat to see exactly how they read it from `/proc` at [`http://procps.sourceforge.net.`](http://procps.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look into writing a Linux Kernel Module (LKM).

There's a tutorial here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/

If you need an accurate profiling system, you can attach your kernel module to some interruption, or any other valid entry point*, and save (with not many instructions!) what you'll need to account. Then, after the interrupt, periodically collect and analyse that data.

You can export the information in the same way that other modules do, via a special file in the filesystem (created in userspace via mknode or within the initialization with MKDEV/register_chrdev).

There's some information in the link above.

`*` For example, you could attach your module to the read syscall (wrap the actual read with yours), or export a file and catch open/close attempts.

An example of usage of the later would be something like:

```
void f() {
  int fd_prof;
  fd_prof = open("/dev/profiler", O_RDONLY);
  /* Do whichever thing you want to profile */
  close(fd_prof);
  /* Read profiled data from /dev/profiled_data or wherever you want
   * to export it to */
```

Please, mind that when compiling a LKM you don't have access to the Standard C Library, as the libc does not exist in kernel space.

Don't worry, you'll still have functions like sprintf implemented in kernel-space, and of course, you have direct access (without context switches) to any syscall (read, write...)

Comment: Uh, quite often modern Linux kernels do not exactly *have* a timer interrupt - at least not with the traditional meaning. An even if they did, its period is at minimum 1ms - about 3 orders of magnitude longer than the precision desired by the OP.

Comment: You are right. However, attaching to that is not the corect way to go. I've edited the post accordingly.

Comment: I was not the one to downvote, but quite honestly I do not believe that this post answers the question. You are essentially telling the OP to create their own kernel-based profiler from scratch and you do not provide any details on the profiling itself...

Comment: Hm. Quite right. I made a little module for class and it didn't hurt so much. Should I delete this answer?